Attaching chain hoist to rafter
I'm looking at getting a 1/4 ton chain hoist and hanging it from the rafters in my shop/garage.  These aren't exactly rafters, but 2x10's put up by a previous owner for "attic" storage.  My question is simply what the best way is to make the attachment.  The hoist has a metal hook.  Should I, for example, loop a section of chain around the wood, or actually mount something through it, or what?


Spreading the weight across a few joists is better.  Laying a 4x4 or 6x6 across four or five joists should work for 2x10 joists.  This carries no guaranty it will not bring the whole thing down on top of you.  You want an engineer for that.

While the joists may appear strong, being 10" wide, they're subject to torsion. Even if they don't crack immediately, under load, they'll gradually twist. As @crip659 states, an engineer should calculate safety margin.

I get being cautious, but we're talking 500 pounds.  That's like 3 normal weight guys standing up there.  It would be really weird for it to fail from that.  But I do like the idea of spanning multiple joists with a 4x4 and attaching to that.

Might only be 500 pounds, but placing that point weight on 2x10 in the centre with a 20ft span is not good.  A hoist is a point weight.  Most joists are rated for pounds per square foot(30 or 40), and a hoist will be pounds(500) per one square inch.  Not exact but gives you an idea.

Understood.  My question remains about how exactly to attach to the 4x4 or whatever I end up with.

I'd be inclined to suggest putting a thick.weight-distribution piece above the rafters and hang the joist from that. You want it to be impossible for fasteners to rip loose. I'd also suggest you consider diagonal-bracing those rafters so they can't tip sideways and fail that way.  But I agree that the best solution is to hire an engineer to inspect the structure and advise you -- not cheap but less than the possible damage to the structure, never mind to the human inside at the time.

Hang from that... how?  That was really my original question.  Like specifically what does the hook on the hoist attach to?

A chain will work.  Chains come with a breaking strength rating.  You want at least 5 to 1 so at minimum a 3000 pound breaking.  Not that big of a chain, maybe 1/4 inch or 3/8 inch size(small chains).

Is it the type of hoist that runs along a track or is a single point anchor?

It just has a hook on the top, so single point.
